# Different colors for different company views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have different companies using my rails site and would like to have different colors displayed in the view depending on the company's colors. How do i implement this?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. The simplest method would be to hard code CSS codes in the head tag, after loading the default CSS. The css code that you hard code can be controlled using ruby so in the application.html.erb

```
  <head>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

    <style>
      #id_where_you_want_to_change_color {
         background-color: <%= current_company.color %>;
      }
    </style>

 </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is to add a class name on a top level element, such as `body`, for applying custom theming and styling per company.

E.g. for the HTML

```
<!-- HTML -->
<body class="company-a"> <!-- substitute company-a for company-b and so on --->
    <ul class="menu"></ul>
</body>
```

...and then in CSS:

```
/* CSS */
.menu {
    background-color: blue; /* default */
}

/* themed for company A */
.company-a .menu {
    background-color: green;
}

/* themed for company B */
.company-b .menu {
    background-color: purple;
}
```

See the excellent presentation [4½ Methods for Theming in (S)CSS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Jz2SrOXup0) by Harry Roberts for more tips and techniques on theming and templating in CSS.

Comment: @A73x15 I'm glad I could help. In return, maybe you could consider marking my answer as accepted.